# iPhoto opens automatically by creating files on Desktop

Tags: macos, keyboard, photos.app, services

**My problem:**

iPhoto opens automatically, when I:

- Copy and paste any kind of file to my Desktop
- Save any file type to my Desktop
- Create a screenshot (which is automatically saved to Desktop)

iPhoto doesn't open when I:

- Move any file type to my Desktop
- Copy and paste a file anywhere in documents (not Desktop)

According to this I think the problem is with *creating a file on the Desktop.*

**When the problem first appeared:**

I tried to create a shortcurt to an application and looked through several blogs. I ended up in creating a test-service, which launches iPhoto.
I wanted to map that service to a shortcut, but it  didn't work out...

[image: photo of automator application]

**What I've tried so far:**

- I've deleted the service I've created.
- I went to System Preferences > Keyboard and "Restored all Defaults" in each category for all the shortcuts.
- I've unchecked every Service in the System Preferences.
- I went through the Preferences of iPhoto.
- I searched Google for like 3 days.

Does anyone has any clue how I can fix this behavior?

**Edit:**

Sorry the confusion: the behaviour hadn't anything to do with the service I've created. It was a Folder Action assigned to my Desktop.

Comment: Have you thought about re-installing iPhoto?

Comment: Yeah - but how do I manage reinstalling it without paying the 15$?

Comment: How did you originally get it? Have you looked in the Mac App store under "Purchases"? If iLife came installed on your computer, it should be available for re-download via the Mac App store.

Comment: It came installed on the computer. When I open up the App Store I can see iPhoto under my purchased apps. However I don't see anything like a button the redownload the app which is described in here: http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/How-To-Re-Download-Apps-From-The-Mac-App-Store.htm

Comment: Should I just go for it? ;)

Comment: I guess I don't see any reason why not (I just hate for there to be some major issue during the un/reinstall process). I just tested it by deleting the Evernote app. I then rebooted and under Purchases in the App store I had the option to "Install". I re-installed Evernote and all worked well, so un/re-install iPhoto *should* be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Folder Actions Setup.

You can open this by right-clicking on any folder in your home folder, choose "Services > Folder Actions Setup ...".

You can also find it here:
/System/Library/CoreServices/Folder Actions Setup.app

Comment: You got it right! It had nothing to do with the service I've created. I launched the Folder Actions Setup and was able to delete another iPhoto.workflow I've created before I set up the iPhoto service.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the service is saved somewhere else? As far as I know, they go into ~/Library/Services/ (you can go there by switching to Finder and press Shift+Control+G or select "go to folder" in the Go-To-Menü).

Maybe you saved your Automator script as "Folder Action"? Have you checked them, too? I think they are visible as a submenu when Control-Clicking on the Desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - the service was saved in /Library/Services, but I deleted it. Unfortunately, I don't see any "Folder Action" when I control-click the Desktop...

Answer (score 1):

Look in the folders

- ~/Library/Scripts
- ~/Library/Application Support/Apple/Automator

if you can find that automator script or workflow with the service where you included iPhoto.

Maybe it got corrupt or something.